# .config directory does not exists after upgrade to Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, folders, catalina

After upgrading to Catalina the .config dir doesn't seem to exist in the home directory of my user.

How can I fix this? I doesn't seem to be able to simply create it because folders starting with a dot are system folder.

Currently my home dir looks like this:

[image]

No wonder some apps like visual studio and brew are complaining about the missing .config-folder.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  I’d you edit your question, show what `df .` shows. Much of your things are true in limited cases, but don’t apply in your case and certainly not in Catalina by default. You might need to show your user and the permissions in the home folder as well.

Answer (score 1):

.config starts with a dot, so it is hidden by default, and ls won’t show hidden files unless you ask it to with the `-a` option.

- Use `ls -a` to list all files/folders including hidden ones.
- Try `ls -a ~/.config` to specifically list the folder you’re looking for.
- Create the folder if it doesn’t exist with `mkdir ~/.config`.